# Is there a tool to check whether I'm using the top N most common words

Tags: discussion

Along the lines of Randall Munroe's tool used to determine whether a word is one of the most common thousand words in English (https://xkcd.com/simplewriter/), I'm wondering if there is a tool that could determine whether a word is one of the most common 2,000 words, or 5,000 words, etc.

Comment: Why not type something like "2000 Most Used English Words" or "5000 Most Used English Words" on your computer ?

Comment: I don't want to merely know what are the most common words. Also, there will be different lists depending on context. I'm looking for a tool that will highlight words from text that are not on a list of N words, where it also handles plurality, derivatives, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you know a little programming (in R or Python, say), there are very easy ways to do this, which I can describe if you want. Otherwise, try using Find on some of the frequency lists given in this page:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists

Comment: I know a lot of programming in many languages. I'm looking for something that includes a UI that will highlight words (and their related word forms) that are (or are not) on a list of N words.

Comment: OK, sounds like you should be able to program it yourself using one of the aforementioned lists, then. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I could, but I was hoping one was already built.